# MVC5 and Javascript relative image paths confusion

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My mvc5 webApp can´t seem to display images if I run it on the virtual server, however if I run it locally it works.

So I have tried several approaches and none that allowed me to run the app on the virtual server or on my pc worked I have tried:

(these worked if I was running this locally)

Images/arrow.png

/Images/arrow.png

This path works for the virtual server but not locally.

webAPP/Images/arrow.png

I know about @Url.Action but I have a lot of different images, around 15, and I don´t know if using @Url.Action is a good idea for that many.

any small example would help tremendously!

Comment: Apparently, `Url.Content` *is* a good idea in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the path to the images from the site root you can do the following in MVC:

```
@Url.Content("~/images/my-image.jpg")
```

The "~/" will map from the site root.

EDIT:
If you're working within a JS file and struggling with relative paths maybe you could add a 'basepath' variable to the top of the file and work with that:

```
var basePath = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images";
```

Then in your code, your image URL returned would be something like:

```
var imgUrl = basePath + "/my-image.jpg";
```

Comment: what if I wanted to show an image in a js file?, Could I add the url.content to a hidden tag and get the path in js?

Comment: Ah, now that is different. Your JS file I presume would deliver the image URL (or constructed IMG tag) to a placeholder on your page. In that case "@Url.Content" wouldn't apply within the scope of the .js file.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
@Url.Content("~/Images/arrow.png")
```

Comment: Or even simpler: `<img src="~/Images/arrow.png" />`